# Laravel saving webm video as mkv

Tags: php, laravel, mediarecorder

I'm uploading a video generated by [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) from the browser to my server:

```js
navigator
  .mediaDevices
  .getDisplayMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      width: { ideal: 1280 },
      height: { ideal: 720 }
    }
  })
  .then(async (stream) => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm' })

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
      const formData = new FormData()

      formData.append('video', e.data)

      axios
          .post(`.../video`, formData, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
          })
    }
  })
```

Then on my Laravel application I have the following code to save the file locally:

```php
public function storeVideo(StoreSessionVideoRequest $request, Session $session): JsonResponse
    {
        $extension = $request->video->extension();

        $request->video->storeAs('videos', "$session->id.$extension");

        $session->video_extension = $extension;
        $session->save();

        // ProcessSessionVideo::dispatch($session);

        return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Video uploaded successfully!']]);
    }
```

The video is being saved as `.mkv` and not as `.webm` as expected. I have tried manually changing the extension to `.webm` but when playing in the browser the video player doesn't recognise the duration of the video and the timeline bar keeps jumping all over the place.

If I use validation to validate only `video/webm` videos I get validation errors - maybe my code in the frontend is not correct?

```php
// The mime type being sent by the frontend is being video/x-matroska
'video' => 'required|file|mimetypes:video/webm,video/x-matroska'
```

How can I save the generated `webm` video by [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) in Laravel and keep it as `webm`?